# how to export records into text file in oracle10g using single query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, export

How do Iexport records into text file in oracle10g, using single query?

I plan to execute any query through jsp/ JDBC and wanna records to be saved in text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/04/28/writing-data-to-a-text-file-from-oracle/